# Area under UINavigationBar does not respond to taps when frame is moved offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I currently have a navigation controller with a UINavBar within my view controller. I hide the navbar by changing the frame x position to a negative value. This hide's the navbar but the area under the navbar no longer responds to touch input. How can I fix this?

Comment: Expand the frame of the underlying view?

Comment: I have already done that. The problem is the area where the navbar used to be does not respond to touch.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the navigation controller with

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

That way your view will resize.

Comment: I don't want to do that because I animate the hide/show of the navigationbar and if I set it to hidden it shifts my other views. Setting the height to 0 seems like a possible solution though.

Comment: If you stick your views to the bottom, they wont shift upward

Answer (score 0):

An easier (and more intuitive) way is to simply modify the View Controller settings. You can remove the NavBar by going to the **Utilities** menu, selecting the **Attributes Inspector**, and then setting "Top Bar" to *None*. Be sure you have the right View Controller selected in the Storyboard.

*Obviously this won't do you any good if you're not using a storyboard. In that case, use Danilo's solution.*